# Mongoengine create_user function generating null objectId's

Tags: django, mongoengine

It always seems to get the exact same error after I've added a single user to the DB.

```
Tried to save duplicate unique keys (E11000 duplicate key error index: mydb.user.$objectId_1  dup key: { : null })
```

What's strange is that I copied the code EXACTLY from the test suite and even that doesn't work. I look at the stack trace and the offending issue is always in the same place

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mongoengine/django/auth.py in set_password
264. self.save()
```

It's incredibly frustrating and I have been looking at this for basically the last 2 days. It's not something in my code. For some reason it doesn't seem to be generating an ObjectId as it's always null. I don't even understand why that's the case

My code is simply

```
from mongoengine.django.auth import User
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

    user_data = {
        'username': 'user',
        'email': 'user@example.com',
        'password': 'test',
    }
    manager = get_user_model()._default_manager
    user = manager.create_user(user_data)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have an extra index on an `objectId` field that is Unique

When creating a new User its not setting an objectId field value and as its unique you can't have two documents without a value (as its not a sparse index).

To test in the mongo shell:

```
> use mydb
> db.user.getIndexes()
```

Drop the `objectId_1` index:

```
> db.user.dropIndex("objectId_1")
> db.user.getIndexes()
```